# Using VLOOKUP to return an array from drop down

Tags: excel-2010, vlookup

This is driving me nuts, so I'll try to explain it best I can.  Basically I have a spreadsheet used to track hours worked on a year's worth of paychecks.  Since it's biweekly, checks are every other week, which means 2 months out of the year there will be months listed 3 times instead of just twice in the list.  So an example for 2016 would be:

```
   A        B          C
1  Jan 08   $1,900.00  Drop Down
2  Jan 22   $1,900.00  Check 1
3  Feb 05   $1,850.00  Check 2
4  Feb 19   $1,800.00  Check 3 if there is one
5  Mar 04   $1,900.00
6  Mar 18   $1,900.00
7  Apr 01   $1,900.00
8  Apr 15   $1,900.00
9  Apr 29   $1,800.00
10 May 13   $1,900.00
11 May 27   $1,900.00
12 Jun 10   $1,900.00
13 Jun 24   $1,850.00
14 Jul 08   $1,900.00
15 Jul 22   $1,900.00
16 Aug 05   $1,900.00
17 Aug 19   $1,900.00
18 Sep 02   $1,900.00
19 Sep 16   $1,900.00
20 Sep 30   $1,900.00
21 Oct 14   $1,900.00
22 Oct 28   $1,900.00
23 Nov 11   $1,900.00
24 Nov 25   $1,900.00
25 Dec 09   $1,900.00
26 Dec 23   $1,900.00
```

Column A contains the dates of the paychecks, Column B contains how much you got paid on that date.  Now, I have a drop down menu that let's you pick a month, and it then displays ONLY the paychecks from that month.

```
C1 = Drop down with January- December
C2 = check 1
C3 = check 2
C4 = check 3 if there is one
```

So I tried to do a VLOOKUP in each cell like this.

```
C2 =VLOOKUP(TEXT(C1,"mmm"),TEXT(A1:B26),2)
```

Obviously this isn't working, and I realised that even if it did work, how am I going to do C3 to display the second paycheck?  Is there anyway to do a VLOOKUP, return all matching values, IE for April it would return A7, A8, and A9, and then put them in order in cells C2-C4?

**EDIT:**
So after some working through suggestions, this is what I have so far:

```
C2=INDEX(A1:B26,(SMALL(IF(MONTH(A1:A26)=MONTH(C1),ROW(A1:A26)),ROW(1:1))),2)
C3=INDEX(A1:B26,(SMALL(IF(MONTH(A1:A26)=MONTH(C1),ROW(A1:A26)),ROW(2:2))),2)
C4=INDEX(A1:B26,(SMALL(IF(MONTH(A1:A26)=MONTH(C1),ROW(A1:A26)),ROW(3:3))),2)
```

C3 and C4 don't work at all.  And C2 only works when I select January, it returns B1, when I select February it returns B2...

Comment: Not with VLOOKUP.. does this help: http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list

Comment: Well, kind of, I tried to use index and match together, but it just returns NA.  INDEX(A1:B26,MATCH(TEXT(C1,"mmm"),A1:A29,0),2)

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to return an array that I can work with.

Comment: I also tried INDEX(A1:B26,MATCH(TEXT(C1,"mmm"),TEXT(A1:A29,"mmm"),0),2)

Comment: Add a column with just the month number or use MONTH function to calculate it. Use this as the lookup column key. VLOOKUP will only show a result in one cell not multiple results. Use INDEX and MATCH instead of VLOOKUP. Use it to find the entry for the month for result 1. Result 2 will be the same formula but offset by 1 row, result 3 will be the same formula but offset by 2 rows unless it's a different month in which case it will be blank.

Comment: Dave, that's what I'm trying to do, it's finding how to do it that's the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer to keep the date format and get the number of month.

Answer (score 1):

I split the date column (see picture) and used the apporach by the link I provided in the comments.

You can enter the name of the month in cell M12. Right next to it you get the matching amount.

The formula for the first occurence of a January paycheck would be:

```
=INDEX($M$1:$O$7,(SMALL(IF($M$1:$M$7=$M$11,ROW($M$1:$M$7)),ROW(1:1))),3)
```

For the second occurence it would be

```
=INDEX($M$1:$O$7,(SMALL(IF($M$1:$M$7=$M$11,ROW($M$1:$M$7)),ROW(2:2))),3)
```

If you insert the formula in the next row you'll get an error (#ZAHL <- it's a German Excel version...).

To mask the error message you can use the ISERROR function as suggested in http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list

[image]

**Edit:**

As OP pointed out a split of month and day is not possible. I suggest to extract the number of the month out of the column (via `MONTH`) and adapt the formula from above:

```
=INDEX($M$1:$O$7,(SMALL(IF(MONTH($M$1:$M$7)=MONTH($M$11),ROW($M$1:$M$7)),ROW(1:1))),3)
```

[image]

Comment: This gets me closer, except I can't split the column, because of another user's process the date column MUST stay "mmm dd".

Comment: Also, are you meaning to use simi-colons in all that?  or are you meaning to use comas?

Comment: So, using what you provided, this is what I ended up with so far:  =INDEX(A1:B26,(SMALL(IF(TEXT(A1:A26,"mmmm")=C1,ROW(A1:A26)),ROW(1:1))),2)
So using that get's me Jan 8 value when I select January, I get Jan 22 value when I select February, and I just get Jan 22 from every month after that.  And changing the row from 1:1 to 2:2 doesn't work at all.

Comment: If you`re not using absolut cell references ($) in your formular then the row change won't work if you copy and paste the formular for the second row.

Comment: Well, I copied his example exactly, and it didn't work at all, I used same cells and values and formulas, his example didn't work.  So I'm not even trying to copy what he did, I'm still working with the example I provided.

Comment: So stepping through it, MONTH($M$1:$M$7) returns #VALUE!

Comment: Is the column formatted as date in your example @Flynn? If not then MONTH won't obviously work.

Comment: Yes, it is formatted, Like I said before, your example MONTH(M1:M7) can't actually be evaluated so it returns false

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$9,SMALL(IF(MONTH($A$1:$A$9)=MONTH($C$1),ROW($A$1:$A$9)-ROW($A$1)+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")}
```